# PROPER capitalize only certain parts of text if fit criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I only PROPER capitalize the first and last portion of what is inside a Excel cell; and leave out what is surrounded by dashes.

Currently I have the following structure in my Excel spreadsheet;

```
JANSON-CT-RELSON
```

When applying the PROPER formula it turns the text into `Janson-Ct-Relson`.

How can I make the formula skill what is inside the dashes? I need it to be:

```
Janson-CT-Relson
```

Comment: Can we assume you'll only have one middle name? Or could you have `ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL`? If so, how do you want to make that, in to `Abc-DEF-GHI-Jkl`?

Comment: No I the middle letters can change but there will only be only two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is by no stretch going to win any beauty pageants, it should work:

```
=PROPER(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1))&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)+1)&PROPER(MID(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,LEN(A1)))
```

Per your comment on the OP, you can tweak it down a little, if we know there's only two initials in the middle:

```
=PROPER(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1))&"-"&MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,2)&"-"&PROPER(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))))
```

Note: This only works for `X-Y-Z`, not `W-X-Y-...-Z` types.